# Haskell: Why can't I use id in another function where id's domain is clearly a superset of the required type in the function?

Tags: haskell

A simple problem here. I'm new to Haskell, playing around with some images using the JuicyPixels package. I've loaded up an image into a `DynamicImage` object in GHCI using `decodePng`. The DynamicImage type is just a wrapper around images with several different pixel types:

```
data DynamicImage =
       -- | A greyscale image.
       ImageY8    (Image Pixel8)
       -- | A greyscale image with 16bit components
     | ImageY16   (Image Pixel16)
       -- | A greyscale HDR image
     | ImageYF    (Image PixelF)
       -- | An image in greyscale with an alpha channel.
     | ImageYA8   (Image PixelYA8)
      -- | An image in greyscale with alpha channel on 16 bits.
     | ImageYA16  (Image PixelYA16)
     ...
```

All I want to do is access the underlying data using `dynamicMap` and see what kind of pixels I am loading. The type signature of dynamicMap uses Rank2Types:

```
dynamicMap :: (forall pixel . (Pixel pixel) => Image pixel -> a)
           -> DynamicImage -> a
dynamicMap f (ImageY8    i) = f i
dynamicMap f (ImageY16   i) = f i
dynamicMap f (ImageYF    i) = f i
dynamicMap f (ImageYA8   i) = f i
...
```

It takes a function from images to anything, a dynamicImage, and that function applied to the underlying data.

Why doesn't

```
getImage :: Pixel a => DynamicImage -> Image a
getImage img = dynamicMap id img
```

typecheck? The error seems to be because the `id` function is too inclusive in its inputs.

```
Couldn't match type `pixel' with `a'
      `pixel' is a rigid type variable bound by
              a type expected by the context:
                Pixel pixel => Image pixel -> Image a
              at <path>:24:16
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            getImage :: Pixel a => DynamicImage -> Image a
          at <path>:23:13
    Expected type: Image pixel -> Image a
      Actual type: Image a -> Image a
    Relevant bindings include
      getImage :: DynamicImage -> Image a
        (bound at <path>:24:1)
    In the first argument of `dynamicMap', namely `id'
    In the expression: dynamicMap id img
```

Comment: In this case, forall is not existential (to the caller) but a universal quantification.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why a universally defined type cannot fill the space for a non-universally defined type.

Comment: You defined the first argument to be a `forall pixel . (Pixel pixel) => Image pixel -> a`. I.E. a thing that takes an image with *any* type of pixel, and returns the desired object type. `id` doesn't do that because it returns a different type depending on the type of pixel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose we have `img :: Image Pixel8` and run

```
getImage (ImageY8 img) :: Image Pixel16
```

How could this get magically converted by code which does not manipulate the bitmaps at all? Surely something is wrong here. Indeed, if the type system allowed this, it would allow a dangerous cast from two different types, likely leading to a crash. In practice, the type system is sound and correctly reject this.

The crucial point is this:

```
dynamicMap :: (forall pixel . (Pixel pixel) => Image pixel -> a)
           -> DynamicImage -> a
```

This type is a contract between the caller and the callee. The caller gets to chose `a`. Then the caller has to pass a function argument of type `forall pixel . (Pixel pixel) => Image pixel -> a`. This has to work on all `pixel` types.
In other words, the callee (`dynamicMap`) gets to choose `pixel`. There is no guarantee that the callee will chose `pixel` so to satisfy `Image pixel ~ a`. Indeed, it won't in the posted code. So, the compiler assumes that `Image pixel` and `a` might be different. But `id` forces them to be the same: the caller is imposing a constraint which limits the choice of the callee.

Hence the type error.

A simpler case:

```
foo :: (forall a. a -> Int) -> Int
foo f = f "hello" + f (42 :: Int) + f True

bar :: Int
bar = foo id
```

Here `bar` passes a function `id :: Int -> Int`, which is not as general as `forall a. a->Int` -- the latter promises to convert anything to an `Int`, callee's choice. So, a type error is reported.

More technically, `id` has type `forall b. b->b`, and we aim for `forall a. a->Int`. There is no way to substitute type `b` (with a type possibly involving the type variable `a`) so that `b->b` becomes `a->Int`.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to assume that Haskell polymorphic types work like OO polymorphic methods. They don't.

The signature `getImage :: Pixel a => DynamicImage -> Image a` is actually shorthand for

```
getImage :: ∀ a . Pixel a => DynamicImage -> Image a
```

An analogous-looking signature in e.g. C# would rather mean something like

```
getImage :: c ~ Pixel => DynamicImage -> (∃ a . c a => Image a)
```

(You can read `∀` and `∃` as `forall` and `exists`, respectively.)

The difference? In Haskell, the `∀ a` shows that this function should work for any type `a` that *the caller can choose* (under the restriction that it's a pixel type). If you choose `a ~ Pixel8`, then `getImage` must be able to offer the image with `Pixel8`, ragardless of what pixel format the input image has.

OTOH, `(∃ a . c a => Image a)` (which is not actually legal Haskell) means that the function return *some* image of *some* type, but the caller has no say in what pixel format it would be. This function would hence in fact be much less useful, unless you specifically want a heterogeneous collection of images. But you can already do that: simply store the `DynamicImage`s as they are!

To properly do existential quantification, a custom ADT is often the best way; if you want to keep it open to *all* `Pixel` instances (even ones that may only be defined in the future) then you can also use proper existentials, but you still need to wrap them in a dedicated `data` type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data DynamicImage' where
  DynamicImage' :: Pixel a => Image a -> DynamicImage'
```

But this is usually much more cumbersome to work with, because you can't just pattern-match on *which specific Pixel type it is*. That is what you should do:

```
Prelude> :m +Codec.Picture.Png
Prelude Codec.Picture.Png> import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
Prelude Codec.Picture.Png BS> Right i <- decodePng <$> BS.readFile "/usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/devices/totem-tv.png" 
Prelude Codec.Picture.Png BS> i`seq`0   -- actually evaluate `i` to the first level,
                                        -- so we can see the pixel type
0
Prelude Codec.Picture.Png BS> :sprint i
i = Codec.Picture.Types.ImageRGBA8 _
Prelude Codec.Picture.Png BS> let Codec.Picture.Types.ImageRGBA8 i8 = i
```

If you've gotten to that point without error, you can then be utterly sure that `i8` will have type `RGBA8`, and you can do anything that's possible with those specific pixels.

Comment: I really miss dynamic dispatch stuff from OO, for example, I'd like to be able to use `show` on the pixel at (0,0) without having to explicitly know what type of pixel it is. From what I've read in the past hour, I can do this using "existential types" correct?

Comment: In principle yes, but that's not a good way to do it. Existentials are awkward. The right way to show a pixel without knowing what type is to do it in a function that accepts concrete, not dynamic, images, but is polymorphic on the pixel type.

Comment: If I wanted to return a "generic pixel" though, I would use existential types, correct?

Comment: Yeah, only, you wouldn't want that. There's nothing useful you could do with a single generic pixel.